# How to find the URL of the linked image in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, images

Getting the following upon opening a word document

[image]

Is there a way to know which URL is it pointing to? Double clicking it does show any info related to path.

Comment: Try toggling field codes. Alt+F9

Comment: Is there no other alternative? That combo only works in `.doc` format whereas in my case it's `.docx`

Comment: Alt+F9 works on .docx files. On many computers, you need to combine it the the Fn key. On Macs, it is Opt+F9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to "File" > "Info" and in the bottom right corner, you will find a button for "Edit Links to Files" (video instruction: https://youtu.be/lMhy9yHh1fA?si=J_CivyJUVChasnmJ&t=23).

In the new window that opens up, you will find a list of all file-links in your document. In my video you can see that I used a link to a local file on my computer. So, in case someone sent you their document and the image was linked to a file on their computer, you can simply point them to where that file should be and tell them that they should send it to you.

Side note: The button "Edit Links to Files" is only available if your image is really a linked image. In your case it looks like it, but for any future reader I want to point that out.